# How to get a single location fix from LocationManager, with a timeout?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am using `LocationManager` to get a single location fix:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private LocationManager lm;
    private ProgressDialog myDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new MyLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, ll);
        myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null , "Determining Your Location", true);
    }

    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                ...

                lm.removeUpdates(this);
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As this stands listening for a location could potentially go on forever if a location fix cannot be found. I want to add some robustness to my code by ceasing to listening for a location after 60 seconds, and displaying an error to the user to saying that their location could not be determined.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a Handler and use postDelayed after 60 sec to stop the listener.

[Handler postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Answer (score 2):

You could either user a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to implement the timeout by calling `LocationManager.removeUpdates` to stop listening.

A `Timer` creates an new thread, which may be overkill. The documentation for `AlarmManager` suggests that "(f)or normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler". The documentation for `Handler` describes one of the main uses for a `Handler` is "to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as (sic) some point in the future."

All signs point to `Handler` as being the most appropriate method of implementing the timeout.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private final int TIMEOUT = 60000;

    private LocationManager myLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            this, null);

        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myLocationManager.removeUpdates(QualityCheckActivity.this);
                // other timeout error code
            }
        };

        Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // location fixed code 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
}
```

*NOTES:*

`TIMEOUT` is, of course, the timeout length in milliseconds. In this case 60,000 milliseconds, or 60 seconds.

I have chosen to implement the `LocationListener` interface on `MyActivity` itself so that the `LocationListener` is easier to access within the `Runnable`.

Instead of calling [`LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)): I'm using [`LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate(java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) which will supply just one location fix.

I deliberately haven't implemented `Activity.onPause` and `Activity.onResume`. Both the location listening, and timeout, will continue if the Activity is paused.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Timer and TimerTask as well. When you create handler to utilise postDelayed, you should be careful of memory leak because the handler still refer your Activity or Service event after they are already finished. PostDelayed will be going to the message queue in the main thread. So, make your handler as static or use weak reference.

You need to consider following code to avoid the memory leak.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

   private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
      WeakReference<MyService> ref;

      public MyHandler(MyService r) {
         ref = = new WeakReference<MyService>(r);
      }

      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

         MyService service = ref.get();
         if (servic==null) {
            return;
         }

         //Do something here
     }

   }

}
```